# How to retrieve Json meta-data from endpoint using django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django rest framework to retrieve data from server.
Now I create a view:

```
class Snipped(APIView):

    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    #@ensure_csrf_cookie
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        request.session["active"] = True
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)


    def post(self, request, format=None):

        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

the model is this:

```
# Create your models here.
class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

so at this point I'd like to know metadata of data passed to this endpoint, I 've found http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/

but if a send OPTION I don't obtain informations about data but only this json answer

```
{
"name": "Snipped",
"description": "",
"renders": [
  "application/json",
  "text/html"
],
"parses": [
  "application/json",
  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "multipart/form-data"
],
}
```

without (see list at http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/)

```
"parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "actions": {
        "POST": {
            "note": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "title",
                "max_length": 100
            }
        }
    }
```

any idea how can achieve above results with an APIView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actions will only work if the view defines a [`get_serializer`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/metadata.py#L68).

You need to define it so you can benefit from the automatic schema generation and return a `SnippetSerializer` instance.

Refer to [generic views](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/cdb8a3c3c86bbb74f17f8880c52000602b015ed4/rest_framework/generics.py#L105-L112) to see an implementation example.

Comment: I've just tryed but no luck seems don't works, can be more specific?thx